# Mongoose query returning only id field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get records based on condition. 
But my query only returning id's instead entire object, why?

**Model**

`productName`

`merchantName`

`postedDate`

`productStatus`

**Query**

```
router.get('/underReview', function(req, res){
Products.find({merchantId: '5a3f781378cfc81a3c4c1cbd'}, {productstus:'Under Review'}, function(err, products){
    if (err){
      throw err;
    }else{
      console.log(products);
      res.json(products);
    }
  });
});
```

**Output**:

```
[{"_id":"5a57ab9dc5e9d82a0ca71d0a"},{"_id":"5a57b0a3e26b842b2c4b560c"}]
```

Comment: Check the typo in `productstus`.

Comment: it's correct :)

Comment: What does it return if you don't filter?

Comment: @zero298   entire collection,

Comment: I want to filter with `and`

Comment: Sorry I should have noticed this earlier. Find method  takes both query and projection document. You are passing second query criteria incorrectly as projection document. If you like to get all fields for a query criteria you have to and both criteria with no projection document. Try `Products.find({merchantId: '5a3f781378cfc81a3c4c1cbd', productstus:'Under Review'}, function(err, products){ ... })`

Comment: @Veeram: thanks, but your query is resulting [ ] as output

Comment: Np. Can you show me a sample document from your collection  ? Are you sure it's not productstatus but productstus in your database ?

Comment: sorry, i missed out one thing, `productstus` is inside `productDetails{}`

Comment: I tried like this : `Products.find({merchantId: '5a3f781378cfc81a3c4c1cbd', productDetails.productstus:'Under Review'}, function(err, products){ ... })`, but i am getting error : `Unexpected token`

Comment: Quotes are needed when you dot notation. Try "productDetails.productstus"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163083/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-veeram).